# STM32 programing failed

Tags: debugging, stm32, stm32f7

I have troubles with programing board with stm32f723 made by me. I am attaching pictures of the programing pins connections. As I connect the st-link of the nucle-l152 board to my board error appears  "The interface firmware FAILED to reset/halt the target MCU". And when I try to flash the program error appears "target not connected".  I cheked the connections, also tried to hold the reset while flashing, also tried different boot modes. Nothing works any ideas ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Jumpers on the nucleo-board are removed.

Comment: Although there's an internal pull-up resistor on the NRST pin, you could try to add an external 10 kOhm resistor between the NRST pin and 3V3 (DW05R, Pin 5, first schematics image). And measure the voltage on the NRST pin, if it is too low, the STM32 stays in reset mode and can't be programmed (see STM32F723xx datasheet, 6.3.21 NRST pin characteristics). (BTW: I had multiple cases where the STM32 still worked but couldn't be programmed anymore, because of some ESD/overvoltage pin damage... always connect the programming cable first before powering the programmer via USB).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about software.  Try electronics.stackexchange.com